# APP launch error: Service could not initialize: 18E226: xpcproxy + 11291

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

I've built an App in Xcode. I've signed it with a valid Developer ID certificate. Notarized and released the app via Archive function in XCode. And the app launches fine on some MacBooks.
But on another launch fails with error

> The application %name% can't be opened.

[image]

I've checked the system.log and it says

> Jul 15 09:59:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVbJn.jpg) (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000ad8.Gaetano Lunches[59755]): Service could not initialize: 18E226: xpcproxy + 11291 [1534][1571C9B2-C489-3268-9D6B-73137AC77303]: 0x1
>
> Jul 15 09:59:40 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVbJn.jpg) (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000ad8. Gaetano Lunches[59755]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78

The app is very simple. It is just a Notification center widget (APP Type XPC!). It receives data from remote URL and displays it via NCWidgetListViewController.

The source code could be found on [github](https://github.com/obukhow/OggettoLunchMac/)

As I mentioned the problem exists only on some machines. The rate is about 50/50. On all machines app installation from Anywhere is allowed. spctl-master is disabled. Permissions for files are correct.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215527/what-does-launchd-status-78-mean-why-my-user-agent-not-running ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked all related questions ) The thing is they are talking about launch agent and my app use notification center widget